# How to write selection(T, i) algorithm for BST tree

Tags: tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

Given the following definition of binary search tree:

```
size(t)={ 0                           , t= null
          1+size(t.left)+size(t.right), otherwise
```

for each vertex in the tree t.size contain the size of its subtree

Write an algorithm which will be named as selection(T, i) with given root to tree T, with size value in each vertex, which will return the value of size i in the tree.

The algorithm should be with minimal complexity time.

Anybody know's how to solve it?

Comment: Do you mean find a vertex with size `i`, and return its value?

Comment: Yes,
Thank you!!!